# Most convenient way to get related object in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I need to render different templates for logged in user depending on its "type":
I have a custom User called `Users` to store the general fields, and three different user types, called `Admins`, `Publishers` and `Copywriters`, linked to the Users table with One-To-One relation

```
class Users(AbstractUser):
    # fields

class Admins(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # extra fields for admins...

class Publishers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # extra fields for publishers...

class Copywriters(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # extra fields for copywriters...
```

Which is the most convenient way tho retrieve the related fields of the logged user? Or in other words, how can i retrieve the admins or publishers or copywriters object related to the logged user?

My original idea was to add a column in the `Users` table called `user_type` but it seems to me a redundant field since there's a One-To-One relation

Comment: Your `user_type` seems to suggest that a user can only be `Admin`, *or* `Publisher`, *or* `CopyWriter`, but not two (or more) at the same time.

Comment: You can access the related object(s) with `my_user.admins`. You should wrap it in a `try ... except AttributeError`, since it is possible that this does not exist.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, an user cannot be two `user_type`s. I could try with `try ... except ObjectDoesNotExist ...`